# Multi-module Maven project that builds a subset of modules

Tags: java, maven, module

Consider a Maven project with the following modules:

- Common (defines common interfaces and utilities)
- ServiceA (depends on Common)
- ServiceB (depends on Common)
- HttpService (depends on Common and either ServiceA or ServiceB)

The modules `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` are mutually exclusive. They both provide the same bean to `HttpService`, but their internals are vastly different. When I build and deploy the application, I want  to only build either one of `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`, depending on an environment variable or build argument.

In my research, I found the `-pl` option of Maven and Maven profiles. `-pl` allows me to explicitly in-/exclude modules from the build. However, I'd prefer something like profiles instead, where I define the options in the root `pom.xml` and only have to provide the corresponding profile name.

When I include

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>a</id>
            <modules>
                <module>Common</module>
                <module>ServiceA</module>
                <module>HttpService</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

and build with `-P a`, then `ServiceB` still gets built.

How should this architecture be defined, so I get only the required modules?

**EDIT**: My root POM is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Common</module>
        <module>HttpService</module>
        <module>ServiceA</module>
        <module>ServiceB</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>a</id>
            <modules>
                <module>Common</module>
                <module>ServiceA</module>
                <module>HttpService</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>b</id>
            <modules>
                <module>Common</module>
                <module>ServiceB</module>
                <module>HttpService</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean package -P a`, all modules still get built:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] untitled                                                           [pom]
[INFO] Common                                                             [jar]
[INFO] HttpService                                                        [jar]
[INFO] ServiceA                                                           [jar]
[INFO] ServiceB                                                           [jar]
[INFO]
```

There is no explicit dependency of `HttpService` to `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`, only to `Common` in its `pom.xml`.

Comment: How would you use `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` conditionally in code?

Comment: My idea is that both provide a bean that implements a certain interface. This bean will be used in `HttpService`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `pom.xml` of submodule `HttpService` now specifies dependencies of both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. Instead, you should also provide profiles settings here:

```xml
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>a</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    ...
                    <artifactId>servicea</artifactId>
                    ...
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>b</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    ...
                    <artifactId>serviceb</artifactId>
                    ...
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Can I also define the `<profiles>` within the `<dependencies>` section or can I define multiple `<dependencies>` sections?

Comment: I am afraid you can't. It violates POM's structure.